# Border-bottom and border-image issues

Tags: html, css

I'm having some issues with border-bottom and border-image.As I understand it I can set an image for my border , in this case I want the image to be :

[image]

However I do not get the image and it just stays a normal 3px border with the color I've specified.And it seems that the image is not taken into consideration.

Can anyone point me to the right direction(Check bootply):

http://www.bootply.com/G5LTvI8YR9

Comment: Post the relevant CSS and HTML in your question.

Comment: There is no image resource on bootply so it is impossible to test it there.

Comment: you should read this: http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/ and for your usecase i'd recommend to use a pseudo element on the link and either use pure css to have a triangle or place your image inside this element.

Comment: I've read it before posting this, didn't do me much good.Maybe I missed something.

Comment: your code works fine with an image linked from google images [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/G5LTvI8YR9#), my guess would be either you tried to link images which were saved in unsopported formatting with wrong extension, or you used an empty part of the image, or the image url was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it through `css` only without using any `image`

### [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/AoM3Kw7KDC)

```
ul.nav a:hover {
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #f39385;
}

ul.nav a:hover:after, ul.nav a:hover:before {
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

ul.nav a:hover:after {
    border-color: rgba(243, 147, 133, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #f39385;
    border-width: 3px;
    margin-left: -3px;
}

ul.nav a:hover:before {
    border-bottom-color: #f39385;
    border-width: -6px;
    margin-left: -6px;
    border-color: rgba(243, 147, 133, 0);
}
```

Comment: This was by far the most convenient solution.

Comment: Yes, much better than using an image, +1

Answer (score 2):

In your case, using a background image on hover state is much simpler than using an image for the border.

I made up this example based on you bootply that should show what you are looking for (The background image is the one you posted, you might need to tweak it and remove unused white parts on the left and right of it so that the triangle is centered) :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Q8gN2/)**

*CSS :*

```
a:hover {
    color: #f39385!important;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIzS3.png) right bottom no-repeat;}
a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #b9b9b9;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    width:112px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3h69R/)**</kbd> if you are interested in CSS solution.

```
<span class="border"></span>

.border {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  background: #f0745f;
  border: 4px solid #f0745f;
}
.border:before,
.border:after {
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.border:before {
  border-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #f0745f;
  border-width: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
.border:after {
  border-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #f0745f;
  border-width: 4px;
  margin-left: -4px;
}
```